# iziModal - resetting the modal title with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using iziModal, but having trouble reusing the same modal in a session. When I click on an item, I am setting the title (and sub-title) accordingly. But it only sets the title the first time. If I click on another entry which loads the modal, the original title is displayed.

Whichever button I press first, the title will reflect that button until the page is refreshed.

Is there a reset method?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<link href="Styles/iziModal.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/izimodal.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Toolbar" width="auto"></div>

<div class="btn btn-danger MODAL1" style="padding-top: 100px;">Modal 1</div>
<div class="btn btn-danger MODAL2" style="padding-top: 100px;">Modal 2</div>

<div id="modal" class="iziModal">        
    <p>This is the Modal content</p>
</div>
</body>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {    

$('.MODAL1').on("click", function (e) {
   ShowModal("This is Modal 1");
});

$('.MODAL2').on("click", function (e) {
   ShowModal("This is Modal 2");
});
});

function ShowModal(Title)
{
$("#modal").iziModal({
    title: Title,
    subtitle: "Simple, complete and lightweight modal plugin with jquery.",
    iconClass: 'icon-stack',
    overlayColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)',
    width: 700,
    padding: 20
});

$('#modal').iziModal('open');
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking in iziModal.js source code, I found reference to setTitle and setSubtitle methods.

So, take the Title and Sub Title out of initialisation, and use the separate methods.

```
function ShowModal(Title)
{
$("#modal").iziModal({                
    iconClass: 'icon-stack',
    overlayColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)',
    width: 700,
    padding: 20
});

$("#modal").iziModal('setTitle',Title);
$("#modal").iziModal('setSubtitle',"SubTitle : " + Title);


$('#modal').iziModal('open');
}
```